# Smooth manifold has infinite dimensional space of smooth vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I want to show smooth manifold has infinite dimensional space of smooth vector field. I know the space of smooth function of a smooth manifold is infinite dimensional.

Then can I just choose a local chart and consider V(p)=f(p)$\frac{\partial} {\partial x}$, and claim that since space of smooth function is infinite dimensional, then so is the space of smooth vector field. I mean if f_1 and f_2 are linear independent, $f_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $f_2\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ should be linear independent.

Comment: More or less. That $V(p)$ is not a global vector field on $M$, but you can multiply this by a cutoff function which is locally constant.

Comment: @JohnMa Of course, you are absolutely right. So after that, I can argue in this way right?

Comment: Yes you are right. Or you can even argue using the fact that $M$ has a countable collection of open sets $U_i$ which are pairwise disjoint, and there are nontrivial smooth vector fields supported on each $U_i$. (Assume $M$ is not a point).

Comment: @JohnMa Get it. By the way, for the definition of manifold, we have local chart that is homeomorphic to an open set in $R^n$. So can we replace the open set with open ball? I mean can we require every local chart is homeomorphic to an open ball without loss of generality?

Comment: Yes, no problem at all.

Comment: @JohnMa OK, thanks!